# Text editor featuring a code tree panel

Tags: javascript, text-editor

My JavaScript file contains some 10 to 20 functions. I am using Notepad++ and I can fold the code in those functions. But I need an extra tab (or box or window) in the same window I am editing where I can see a list (or tree) with all those functions. So I can click on any function and then to jump with the cursor at the function that I clicked on.

The functions list/tree window should look something similar with the file list in the Atom editor (that tab placed to the left of the editing area)

I don't know if Notepad++ has such a feature but maybe there is some editor capable to do that?

Later edit: I changed the title of the question. I didn't know it's called "Code tree panel"

Comment: Some people, when confronted with coding, think "I know, I'll use Notepadd++." Now they have two problems.  ([Sorry](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski) - I couldn't resist it. I love Notepad++ and use it daily, but at home and work - ***for text***. For code, use an IDE. You will get refactoring, jump to function/variable declaration/usage, code completion, documentation of system functions, and, most importantly a debugger. If you don't have one or don't know how to use one, stop coding ***now*** and learn. You will save ***a lot*** of time.

Comment: An IDE is even more important for an interpreted language like JS, as most good IDEs have a [Linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)). Notepad++ is excellent, but it won't tell you when you mis-spell a variable name, or worse.

Comment: With a good IDE, although you ***can*** fold code, I never bother to. What’s the point? It is generally only used to make it easier to navigate through your code.  With a good IDE I can easily pull up a list of functions in a given file, click and jump to one. I can see that my code accesses a variable or function and jump to its declaration, or all uses of it. Why would I want to fold code?

Comment: @Mawg Any text editor supporting syntax coloring for a language should be able to have a linter for that language. Atom and VSCode and probably many others have js linters.

Comment: Those are IDEs. Notepad++ is not an IDE and does note, AFAIK, support a linter. The main pint though is the debugger. ***No feature*** is more important than having a debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor (light and free) has Code Tree panel with function list. Toggled by F12. Supported for many syntaxes, JavaScript too.

[image: CudaText JS tree]

Comment: Thanks, it works, and it is much litghter than Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of VS Code have a "Code Outline View".

The function names in that panel (see lower left in screenshot) are clickable and will move to the function definition in the JS file.

[image]